# Which package provides a given jar?

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dpkg, synaptic

How can I determine which apt package I should install to have a certain jar file?

BTW: I'm actually looking to solve

```
XML parser factory has not been configured correctly: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
```

but I wish to find a general solution.

Let's do it by example:

- I miss org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
- so I can use http://search.maven.com and determin that I need xerces-1.4.4.jar
- but in which ubuntu package is that jar located?

Comment: Where is the jar file?

Comment: Try `dpkg -S /path/filename.jar`

Comment: @AvinashRaj the jar isn't there yet ... I wish to find the right package to install

Comment: Unclear, please be specific.

Comment: `apt-file search /name/of/the/file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install libxerces2-java:

```
sudo apt-get install libxerces2-java
```

To actually find the right package, try using the powerful http://packages.ubuntu.com using the query on package content:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xerces+jar&mode=filename&suite=saucy&arch=any

Comment: That solves the problem but it does not answer the question ;)

Comment: You're right, I've added a link to http://packages.ubuntu.com